# Slide to unlock to avoid spam

Tags: javascript, spam-prevention

I've searched but it seems a new question.

My personal website is a simple html page with a contact form.

I have reCAPTCHA before submit to a lambda function, but I still receive 5/8 spam contacts per day and it is really annoying.

I've read suggestion about hidden fields and simple questions (I'm going with those if this is only a bad idea), but: **what about a IOS style "Slide to submit" instead of the classic submit button?**

Maybe the bots are not able to handle that..? Do you already know that this is a bad idea?

I don't care too much about users with js disabled, I already let them know that they need js to submit..

Thanks if you have an answer!

Comment: (a) The core of your question ("*Do you already know that this is a bad idea?*") is *way* too opinion-based for Stack Overflow's scope per the [help/on-topic]. Questions here are expected to leverage facts from verifiable sources to provide concrete answers to focused technical questions. (b) Please consider the accessibility nightmare such a feature might create for folks using alternative browsers and accessible technologies to your site. Mitigating such an objectively low volume of spam should not come at the expense of accessibility for disabled users.

Comment: Yeah you have a point here.. Didn't thought about disabled people.. Thanks for both responses!